# Stop one global query filter for one read operation only

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 global query filters one for soft delete and one for multi-tenancy 
I am wondering if I could stop one global query filter in Entity framework 3.0 for just one read operation and it get back to work automatically?

Answer (score 0):

For now, Entity framework Global Query filters does not allow disabling of a specific filter. But if required we can disable all the filters and then, manually apply them in the where clause.

```
context.Customers
    .IgnoreQueryFilters().ToList();
```

If you want this functionality and freedom of enabling disabling each filter, you should consider Entity framework dynamic filters library. Here is the github link to it. https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters

Comment: Also since query filters are configured in OnModelCreating, you can create multiple DbContext subtypes that have different query filters enabled.

Comment: I have done it already through adding extra parameter with the filter expression which it's values is equal true always and I make it equal false when I need to stop the filter, but I need the filter to go back to work after one read operation